# 3-manifolds, cubes with handles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology

Somebody knows where I can find some proof of the following fact:
If F is compact, connected 2-manifold with nonempty boundery why there exist n=1-X(F) pairwise disjoint properly embedded 1-cells {A1,...,An} in F which cut F to a 2-cell.

This claim is formulated in a proof of theorem 2.3, 3-manifolds, John Hempel

Comment: This is better suited to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This is the classification theorem for compact 2-manifolds.  You can find a proof in a variety of places.  Singer and Thorpe's "Lecture Notes on Elementary Geometry and Topology" is a nice one.   That's a bit old, though.  I think this is also in many of the textbooks by Stillwell that involve surfaces. Proofs boil down to triangulability + Poincare duality + the simply connected case. 

Answer (score 2):

This is not really an answer, but not really a comment either.

You can start from the classification theorem of compact surfaces (every compact connected 2-manifold is homeomorphic to either a connected sum of $g$ tori or a connected sum of $k$ projective planes, with a finite number of disks removed). To prove this you need the triangulation theorem, which is proved in Moise's *Geometric Topology in Dimensions 2 and 3*, and once you have a triangulation you can prove by hand that you will always get a connected sum of tori or projective planes.

After that, you can prove the result you want by hand by drawing nice pictures :)